# How to insert dates from one data frame into another?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with two columns, one containing dates, the other numbers. My goal is to insert dates from another data frame into the date column. Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(rep(as.Date("2001-01-01", origin = "1970-01-01"), 3),
                 c(1, 2, 3), 
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
ins <- data.frame(rep(as.Date("1999-01-01", origin = "1970-01-01"), 3), 
                  c(1, 2, 3),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
```

The data frame I want to obtain is:

```
> df_goal
       dates numbers
1 1999-01-01       1
2 2001-01-01       2
3 2001-01-01       3
```

I tried `df[1, ] <- c(ins[1, 1], ins[1, 2])`, but I got the following error:

> Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied

However, if in `df` I omitt the numeric column, it works:

```
df <- data.frame(rep(as.Date("2001-01-01"), 3), 
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
ins <- data.frame(rep(as.Date("1999-01-01"), 3), 
                  c(1, 2, 3),
                  stringsAsFactors = F) 
df[1, ] <- ins[1, 1]
```

How to get the first case (`df` with two columns) working?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Don't use `c` -- it transforms its arguments so they have the same class. You can do `df[1,] <- ins[1, c(1,2)]`. But also: don't do this sort of insertion; there must be a better way to achieve what you're after, like a join/merge.

Comment: @Frank: If your comment were an answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried `df[1, ] <- c(ins[1, 1], ins[1, 2])`, but I got the following error:
>
> > Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied

Don't use `c` -- it transforms its arguments so they have the same class.

In this case, `c(ins[1, 1], ins[1, 2])` makes a date vector; and when this is assigned onto the second column of `df`, R tries to coerce that column to date to make sense of the assignment, like `as.Date(c(1, 2, 3))`.

You can instead do `df[1,] <- ins[1, c(1,2)]`.

---

*Side note*: Don't do this sort of insertion based on row numbers; there must be a better way to achieve what you're after, like a join/merge.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
df2 <- rbind(ins[1,], df[2:3,])
```

or

```
df2 <- df
df2[1,] <- ins[1,]
```